# Exclude generated code in sonar

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, sonarqube

**How to exclude generated code from sonar processing and reporting?**

I tried to [exclude](http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/Is-is-possible-to-exclude-code-from-coverage-or-style-check-tt3198093.html#a3198096) `**/*generated*` but packages like `org.blayo.generated` are still in report:

```xml
<plugin>
  ...
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>

    <excludes>**/*generated*</excludes>
```

**Edit:** The right regular expression was `**/generated/*.java`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `sonar.exclusions` property for this:

```xml
<properties> 
  <sonar.exclusions>**/*generated*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 17):

The exclusion pattern has **changed since SonarQube 3.5**. Here is how it works now:

```xml
<properties>
   <sonar.exclusions>file:**/generated-sources/**</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Source: [SonarQube JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2760)

Comment: This was the pattern which finally got it working for me

Comment: It will work without the **file:** prefix, it is the [wildcard syntax](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns) that's important (at least in SonarQube 6/7).  Using `<sonar.exclusions>target/generated-sources/**</sonar.exclusions>` is a minor improvement.